# How to setup SSD's in RAID 5 on a MSA2060?

Tags: raid, ssd

In the near future we want to replace our current MSA2050 with SAS disks to a MSA2060 with 10 SSD disks (HPE, 960GB each). We are going to use RAID 5.

Since RAID 5 can go up to 16 disks, we can make 1 cluster of 10 disks.

Is this good practice (subjective), but more important -> why?

Or is the way to go making 2 clusters of 5 disks (subjective), but more important -> why?

How is read/write performance between 1 cluster or 2 clusters?

Naturally, 2 clusters will have lower usable storage with 2 parity disks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

10 drives make an excellent RAID6 array.

An array performs best when the number of drives is a power of 2 (e.g. 8) plus the drives required for redundancy (2 for RAID6). 8+2=10

RAID5 with a larger number of drives is prone to failing when rebuilding a failed disk: a single read errors on any of the remaining drives is enough to fail the rebuild and kill the array.

A RAID 50 (striping over RAID5 subarrays) might be faster but a single RAID6 is more reliable.